# Set an array in cookie in codeigniter site

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am developing a codeigniter site. Here is my controller function:

```
public function hoteldetails($id)
{
    $this->load->helper('cookie');
    $hotel_details_view = array();


    $hotel_details_view = get_cookie('hotel_details_view');
    array_push($hotel_details_view, $id);

    $this->input->set_cookie($hotel_details_view);
    print_r($hotel_details_view);
    $this->load->view('hotel_details',$data);

}
```

Now I want to set multiple $id in cookie at the time of function calling

I get the error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given
>
> Filename: controllers/hotel.php
>
> Line Number: 191

I need help :)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** try this:

```
public function hoteldetails($id)
{
    $this->load->helper('cookie');

    $hotel_details_view = array();
    $cookieValue = get_cookie('hotel_details_view');     
    $hotel_details_view[] = $cookieValue;
    $hotel_details_view[] = $id;

    $this->input->set_cookie($hotel_details_view);
    print_r($hotel_details_view);
    $this->load->view('hotel_details',$data);
}
```

`$hotel_details_view` array is overwrite with the `$hotel_details_view` string value that you are getting from `get_cookie()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
public function hoteldetails($id)
{
    $this->load->helper('cookie');
    $hotel_details_view = array();  
    $hotel_details_view = get_cookie('hotel_details_view');
    $hotel_details_view[] = $id;
    $this->input->set_cookie($hotel_details_view);
    print_r($hotel_details_view);
    $this->load->view('hotel_details',$data);

}
?>
```

Comment: It's only add one id in array.

Comment: print your cookie before pushing into array `print_r($hotel_details_view);`